# Counting sub-string occurrences in a string

Tags: python

I want to write a loop in python that checks the first three letter from 0-2 for a certain word then checks the next letters from 1-3 for the same word.

This is my code so far, it always just prints out 1 after any input.

```
Count = 0
start = 0
end = start + 2
word = 'dad'
string = input('Type in a word')

for word in string[start-end]:
    if word in string:
         Count = Count + 1
    start = start + 1

print (Count)
```

Could someone help me please?

Comment: What is wrong with a simple `string.count(word)`.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? What exactly are you checking for? Can you show an example input and what your expected output is

Comment: You never update the `end` variable in the loop, that might be why it's stopping to count at 1.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but note that `string[start-end]` is not the correct syntax for getting the substring of `string` starting at `start` and ending at `end`.

Comment: Reading between the lines - are you ultimately trying to find the number of occurrences of a substring (including overlaps) in a target string? Eg... `dad` appears twice in `dadad` (rather than `str.count` which will give you 1 instead...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to optimise the code. This code works for overlapping while for non-overlapping matches `count` can be used.

```
string = 'dadada'
substring = 'dad'
results = 0
sub_len = len(substring)
for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[i:i+sub_len] == substring:
        results += 1
print results
```

**alternative**

Although this process suits the OP but for future visitors its better to have advance alternatives.
As suggested in the comment section.

```
import re
results = sum(1 for _ in re.finditer('(?=dad)', 'dadada'))
```

this functionality uses positive lookahead of regex for finding the solution the reason of the use `sum` and `for` loop is to find the number of iteration as `finditer` returns iterator.

user can also try `len(list(re.finditer('(?=dad)', 'dadada')))` which will convert the iterator to list and find the length.

**non-re alternative**

```
string = 'dadada'
sub = 'dad'
print len([n for n in xrange(len(string)) if string.find(sub, n) == n])
```

This is an implementation with custom method `find` function of `str`. If we remove `len` we can get the list of indexes.

Comment: Or even something like: `results = sum(1 for _ in re.finditer('(?=dad)', 'dadada'))
`

Comment: agree also results = len(list(re.finditer('(?=dad)', 'dadada')))

Comment: True, but no real need to build a list there of all the match objects to take its length when we just want the count...

Comment: re.findall can also be used although i am sure lots of different approach can be used for the context. Thought to stick to for loop. Would you like me to update the answer?

Comment: You can add alternative approaches if you want - up to you. Mind you - I expect the OP is probably expected to use something similar to the approach you've suggested... (or maybe even using `str.index` with the start argument...)

Answer (score 0):

```
    word = 'dad'
    string = input('Type in a word')
    print (string.count(word))
```

I think that's all you looking for

Comment: this works for non-overlapping matches. not for overlapping one